# Is it possible to add 2 new input fields after clicking a button?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

So currently I am learning Python with PyQt5.

My current projects is a very simple database, that saves data in a CSV file.

The way my project will be working is.

1. You will name your "database" and save it.
2. By clicking a Button you will add 1 new column into the database, and 2 new input fields

   - input field 1 - here you will create a name for a new column
   - input field 2 - in here you will write your text/numbers (data) which will be added into the database

   -> little try of Graphical presentation
   -

- ( click to add column -> column 1 )
- ( button clicked -> column 1 column 2 )
- ( click to add column -> column 1 column 2)
- ( button clicked -> column 1 column 2 column 3 )

3. After naming the column and adding some text into the data part you will then click one of two buttons

   - One button will rename your columns if you decide to change the name
   - The second will colect all data from input fields and add them into the database
4. Save your database so that you can open it later

So my problems right now is I don't know how to create step 2).
I tried to use List and then loop through it, to display, but I don't know how to create this.

So I am asking for help.Shoudl I abandon this aproach ? or is there a better way of doing this ?
I am not creating this to sell it, I am creating this only for peronal use.
Also I apologize for badly writen and readable code, I am new to Python and overall programing

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, Qt
import sys, os
import pandas as pD
import csv

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(**kwargs)
                
        self.setWindowTitle('Databáze')
        self.init_GUI()
        self.show()
        
    def init_GUI(self):
               
        database = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        database_Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        database.setLayout(database_Layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(database)
        
        self.createUI(database_Layout)
    
    def createUI(self, database_Layout):
        
        fileHandling_Layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        editableEntries_Layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        table_Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.fileName_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Název souboru: ')
        self.fileName_Label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',15))
        self.fileName_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.fileName_edit_TEXT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.fileName_edit_TEXT.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',13))
        self.fileName_edit_TEXT.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        
        self.saveFile_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Uložit jako')
        self.saveFile_Button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',10))
        self.saveFile_Button.setFixedSize(90,40)
        
        self.openFile_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Otevřít soubor')
        self.openFile_Button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',10))
        self.openFile_Button.setFixedSize(90,40)
        
        fileHandling_Layout.addWidget(self.fileName_Label)
        fileHandling_Layout.addWidget(self.fileName_edit_TEXT)
        fileHandling_Layout.addWidget(self.saveFile_Button)
        fileHandling_Layout.addWidget(self.openFile_Button)
 
        #ADD NEW INPUT FIELDS ( ADDS NEW COLUMN INTO DATABASE )
        self.addNewEntrie_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Nový prvek')
        self.addNewEntrie_Button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',10))
        self.addNewEntrie_Button.setFixedSize(80,40)
        self.addNewEntrie_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color : lightBlue")

        editableEntries_Layout.addWidget(self.addNewEntrie_Button)

        newEntrie_Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        #COLUMN NAME
        self.column_Name_Edit_TEXT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.column_Name_Edit_TEXT.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',15))
        self.column_Name_Edit_TEXT.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.column_Name_Edit_TEXT.setFixedSize(150,30)
        
        #DATA TO PUT INTO ROW
        self.row_Data_EDIT_TEXT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.row_Data_EDIT_TEXT.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',13))
        self.row_Data_EDIT_TEXT.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.row_Data_EDIT_TEXT.setFixedSize(150,25)

        newEntrie_Layout.addWidget(self.column_Name_Edit_TEXT)
        newEntrie_Layout.addWidget(self.row_Data_EDIT_TEXT)
        
        newlyCreatedEntrie_Layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        
        newlyCreatedEntrie_Layout.addLayout(newEntrie_Layout)
        
        editableEntries_Layout.addLayout(newlyCreatedEntrie_Layout)
        
        entries_Buttons_Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.renameColumn_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Přejmenuj sloupec')
        self.renameColumn_Button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',10))
        self.renameColumn_Button.setFixedSize(115,40)
        self.renameColumn_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color : lightBlue")
        
        self.addData_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Přidej data')
        self.addData_Button.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial',10))
        self.addData_Button.setFixedSize(115,40)
        self.addData_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color : lightBlue")
        
        entries_Buttons_Layout.addWidget(self.renameColumn_Button)
        entries_Buttons_Layout.addWidget(self.addData_Button)
        editableEntries_Layout.addLayout(entries_Buttons_Layout)

        self.table_Database = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        table_Layout.addWidget(self.table_Database)
        
        database_Layout.addLayout(fileHandling_Layout)
        database_Layout.addLayout(editableEntries_Layout)
        database_Layout.addLayout(table_Layout)
    
        
aplikace = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
okno = Window()
sys.exit(aplikace.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create the widgets dynamically and then add them to your layout.
In the simplest form:

```
buttonToClick = QPushButton()
self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
buttonToClick.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

def buttonClicked(self):
    inputField1 = QLineEdit()
    inputField2 = QLineEdit()
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(inputField1)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(inputField2)
```

And you can write your logic inside this function to create the new column

Comment: That is actually smart, I tried creating new Class called Entry and adding that into a list every time you clicked the button, but this is actually easier. Thank you for your help

Comment: sorry, I am new to this site I didn't know you could do this, Your answer has worked perfectly, hoewer I had to remove the self from -> def buttonClicked() after that it works as I want Thank you